# How can I stop the automatic redirection to "/pages/default.aspx"?

Tags: 2010, web

When user goes to `http://site/web/` I do not want them to be redirected to that web's welcome page, `http://site/web/pages/default.aspx`.

How can I disable this redirection?

I am fully aware this would result in a 404 error which is what I want.

Comment: Could you just set the welcome page to a custom error page?

Comment: This would still redirect. I want to disable this redirection altogether.

Comment: I know. I don't think you can disable it. I was suggesting an alternative that works with SharePoint rather than against it.

Comment: Added my solution below. Thanks @rjcup3 for the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I came up with:

```
web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
SPFolder rootFolder = web.RootFolder;
rootFolder.WelcomePage = "";
rootFolder.Update();
web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
```

This works great. Will probably add this snippet to an event receiver when new webs are created.

Note: Setting the Welcome Page to nothing (`""`) can only be done pragmatically. The `/_Layouts/AreaWelcomePage.aspx` page won't let you do this.

Answer (score 1):

you can also open up SharePoint designer.  Create a new page, right click, select "set as home page", then delete the page.

**Edit**

Be sure to create the page at the root of the site and not in "pages" or you will still get /pages in the URL (although it will still throw a 404).

Comment: Ha. Never tried that in SharePoint designer.

Comment: Technically the redirect still happens, but it redirects to a page that doesn't exist, thus throwing a 404.

Comment: Yes, which is why I can't accept it. My answer below does disable this redirection.